# How to write this schedule in crontab?

Tags: cron

I want to run a command 7 to 24 o'clock every two minutes and 24 to the next day 7 o'clock every 10 minutes.

I write

`*/2 7-24 * * * command`

`*/10 24-7 * * * command`

But `crontab` tells me it has problem.So how to fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Midnight is 0, not 24. Furthermore, each column works independently, so `7-23` means “whenever the hour part of the time is between 7 and 23 inclusive”, not “between 7:00 and 23:00”. So use `7-23` for “7:00 till midnight” and `0-6` for “midnight till 7:00”.

```
*/2 7-23 * * * command
*/10 0-6 * * * command
```